# Why does the Visual Studio Node.js projects use a shebang/bash script to start server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2015

In the visual studio node.js projects they have a bin directory with a file named www with this contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3300);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('server up and running on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Is the right name for this a bash script? Why would you take this approach versus just having it in your app.js? Does it have something to do with deployment or portability?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convention in node apps is that we create the main js file to run the server at `bin/` folder in a file called `www`which is to be run by `node.exe`. One reason is to seperate your app logic from the place which has the start point. Ofcourse you could add it inline in the `app.js` or infact have a `server.js` file at the same directory of `app.js` to do the same thing. It's upto you to choose the entry point into the app. With deployment, again depends on your specific environment. Certain services like Azure Web APPs by default run server.js (though ofcourse you can include a config file to specify your entry point).

Also this is still a javascript file and not bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

means run by executable node from /usr/bin/env

```
#!/bin/bash
```

means run by executable bash at /bin/bash

Both are different in syntax. Sample Codes to print if a variable foo is even in

Bash Script:

```
if [ $((foo%2)) -eq 0 ];
then
    echo "even";
else
    echo "odd";
fi
```

Javascript:

```
if(foo%2==0)
    console.log(“even”);
else
    console.log(“odd”);
```